# AlienFX on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, alienware, keyboard-backlight

I'd like to be able to run Alien FX on my computer to change the lights on my Alienware MX 14 R2. I see several links in a Google search, but none of them seem to work. [This one](https://github.com/acyed/qtFx) looks promising, but it's only for newer models. [This one](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/alienfx-lite-linux-windows-alienfx-tool.458528/) looks like exactly what I want but it won't work for me--either because it's for an older version of Linux or it just only works with the original model of my computer and not the R2 one.

Has anyone seen any other Alien FX programs for Linux? Or does anyone think they could edit one of these to work with my computer? I know it'll be hard to answer this question since you basically need my exact computer to see if it will work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your first link says it is for newer models. But it was released in 2013 so it probably includes R2 and R3.

Comment: Yeah, but I tried it and it didn't work. :(

Comment: Just curious if you've made any progress on this issue? I never did get a chance to test my AW17R3 in Linux. It's still the factory default dark blue on all the LEDs / Trons. You know if you set it in Windows 10 it will carry over to Ubuntu right?

Comment: No, I haven't. The package below may work, but I never got a chance to try it because my friend (it's his computer) decided to go back to Windows 10 because "nothing works." This and two other programs were the only things that didn't work and I was about to fix this buuut.….

Comment: I tried AlienFxLite on Alienware-13R3 but I get error saying "Device Uknown: no controller available". It seems Alienware-13R3 is not yet supported.

Comment: @user1436887 See my revised answer below.

Comment: IMO the easiest way to change the colors if you've kept around your windows install (hopefully it's air-gapped!) is to use the bundled dell alienfx software in windows. The LED settings will persist when you reboot into linux.

Answer (score 4):

### Update: July 20 2019

A deleted answer below points out how AW13R3 is not supported. It appears that **AlienFXLite** and **PyALienFX** have both been abandoned for a number of years.

I've found a github page for **AKBL** (Alienware Keyboard Lights) to control [Alienware Light Effects](https://github.com/rsm-gh/akbl). **AKBL** was updated just 10 days ago:

[image: AKBL GUI.png]

Sadly I've had this AW17R3 laptop for almost two years but have never found time to "play with" the light effects. This new program **AKBL** looks promising as it's written in Python and does some cool thing such as change light colors depending on the weather outside.

Some cool ideas off the top of my head would be setting colors based on CPU%:

- <10%=green, 10-20%=blue, 20-30%=yellow, 30-4%0=orange, 40-50%=purple, 50+%=red.

---

### Original Answer

I found this package: [AlienFxLite](https://github.com/bchretien/AlienFxLite)

[image: AlienFx lite.png]

> This software was initially developed for M15x and M17x laptops. The
> latest modifications were tested on the M14x R2 and R3 laptops.

Disadvantage as you need to compile it.

---

There is also a newer package: [alienfx](https://github.com/trackmastersteve/alienfx)

[image: alienfx.png]

Advantages:

- Comes with `.deb` package for Ubuntu installation
- Last updated 1 months ago (July 2018).
- Your laptop appears supported  as device #10 and mine as device #14: https://github.com/trackmastersteve/alienfx/blob/master/docs/Knowledgebase/Devicelist.md

I'll try to test this on my AW17R3 soon and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found [something that works](https://github.com/snooze6/hack-alienfx).
https://github.com/snooze6/hack-alienfx

Clone the above repo and run:

```
cd hack-alienfx
make all
sudo ./run seq/snooze
```

But above program is written for device id 187c:0527 
so in the source code replace it with your own alienfx device ids.

run `$lsusb` to find your alienfx device id:

> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 187c:0529 Alienware Corporation

```
cd hack-alienfx
grep -rin "0527" ./
```

I replaced all occurances of 0527 with 0529 in the source files.

```
make all
sudo ./run seq/snooze
sudo ./run seq/afx-godark
sudo ./run seq/afx-off
sudo ./run seq/afx-allblue
```

The commands in `seq/` folder are written for device 187c:0527. So it doesn't behave according to command name. But at least I can now turn on/off lights.

Comment: Mine is close: `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 187c:0528 Alienware Corporation ` I will try to test it (someday) ...

Comment: It works for me, thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Based in an old alienfx I have the only this zones for 0528 I have alienware 15 R1

Z13 special function left
Z14 Turbine right
z15 Turbina left 
z20 Logo ALIENWARE screen
z21 logo and lines back
z23 keyboard 1  left to right
z24  keyboard 2
z25  keyboard 3
z26  keyboard 4

some one have another with the new version dont work but win old aliewn fx 1 this coomand work

Alien 15 :          sudo alienfx -P 0528 -c  z00f117 blue
Alien 15 off:    sudo alienfx -P 0528 -c  z00f000